# do X in column A if Y found in column B

Tags: mysql

i have done some research on this matter and found that this works and is fairly easy:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `A`=A+200 WHERE B='Y';
```

this works obviously if column B has only a single Y value.

but here comes the 'hard' part. column B has multiple values like this: ,Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4,

i would like A+200 to be executed only if Y3 is found in column B regardless of what the other values are. i am not too familiar with arrays or whatever is required to search through column B for the Y3 value. any help is appreciated. thank you!

Comment: Actually this has nothing to do with PHP or phpMyAdmin.

Comment: If `B` is really in the form `Y1,Y2,...` it is badly normalized. This should be fixed in order to have a useful database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) or match against a regular expression with [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

Example:

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `A` = `A` + 200
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Y3', `B`)
```

or

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `A` = `A` + 200
WHERE `B` REGEXP '(^|,)Y3(,|$)'
```

aaand what glglgl said. Normalize your database: [Wikipedia: Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms)

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE table` SET A=A+200 where find_in_set('Y3',YOUR_COLUMN);
```

Comment: And what about this value for `B`: `Y1,Y33,Y4` ?

Comment: `UPDATE table SET A=A+200 WHERE B lIKE 'Y%';` try this. Posted as an answer as well

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `table` SET `A`=A+200 WHERE B='Y3';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `table` SET `A` = A + 200 WHERE `B` LIKE 'Y%';
```

try this. It means update the table where B starts with Y and doen't matter what is next ;)